# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'google/protobuf/api.proto'

Tags: angular, firebase, webpack, angularfire, server-side-rendering

I want to integrate angular universal into my project and I use AngularFire library. But when I test my app locally by running npm run build && npm run serve:ssr.

I have this error

```
  webpack:///./dist/server/main.js?:95613
                throw err;
                ^

    Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'google/protobuf/api.proto'
        at Object.openSync (fs.js:440:3)
        at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:342:35)
        at fetch (webpack:///./dist/server/main.js?:95679:34)
        at Root.load (webpack:///./dist/server/main.js?:95713:13)
        at Root.loadSync (webpack:///./dist/server/main.js?:95754:17)
        at Object.loadSync (webpack:///./dist/server/main.js?:133270:17)
        at Object.8ZNE (webpack:///./dist/server/main.js?:98662:37)
        at __webpack_require__ (webpack:///./dist/server/main.js?:20:30)
        at Object.BYZf (webpack:///./dist/server/main.js?:104679:19)
        at __webpack_require__ (webpack:///./dist/server/main.js?:20:30) {
      errno: -2,
      syscall: 'open',
      code: 'ENOENT',

  path: 'google/protobuf/api.proto'
```

Answer (score 14):

I got this from another post, but it did help me out to fix that error (I had been looking for fixes for a while now).

Hope it works for you

angular.json

```
"server": {
  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
    "options": {
      "outputPath": "dist/TeacherKellyUKA/server",
      "main": "server.ts",
      "tsConfig": "tsconfig.server.json",
      "externalDependencies": ["@firebase/firestore"]
  },
```

Comment: More detail on this issue: https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/2424#issuecomment-619239036

Comment: bravo...I have been looking for a solution for 2 days...thank you so much...

Comment: Hi @jessemoon0, after adding externalDependencies, I am getting this error.
Schema validation failed with the following errors:
  Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(externalDependencies). how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with AngularFirestoreModule. I have updated below line in package.json and it is working fine. I am using angular version 8.

"bundleDependencies all" to "bundleDependencies none"

```
"build:client-and-server-bundles": "ng build --prod && ng run web:server:production --bundleDependencies none"
```

Answer (score 0):

Applying solution provided by [@essemoon0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10339934/jessemoon0) fixed the error. Running `firebase serve` worked well. However, running `firebase deploy` brought another issue `cannot find module @firebase/firestore`. After many trials I was able to find a solution.

As projected by [@essemoon0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10339934/jessemoon0) , first add `@firebase/firestore` as an external dependency in `angular.json` as follows

```
"server": {
  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
    "options": {
      "outputPath": "dist/TeacherKellyUKA/server",
      "main": "server.ts",
      "tsConfig": "tsconfig.server.json",
      "externalDependencies": ["@firebase/firestore"]
  },
```

Then navigate to your `functions` directory and install `@firebase/firestore` and `firebase/app` packages.

```
cd functions

npm i @firebase/app @firebase/firestore
```

Now you can run your app.
This worked for me. Hope it does for you.